# How to orderByChild in nested Child in angularfire?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

My firebase database structure is as below. I would like to search with a particular "Info/Email", let's say "abc@abc.com".

```json
    {  
      "-KhWrBcYyMluJbK7QpnK" : {
        "Info" : {
          "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com"
        },
        "Settings" : {
          "Status" : "Accepted"
        }
      },
      "-KhX0tgQvDtDYqt4XRoL" : {
        "Info" : {
          "Email" : "abc@abc.com"
        },
        "Settings" : {
          "Status" : "Accepted"
        }
      },
      "-KhX1eo7uFnOxqncDXQ5" : {
        "Info" : {
          "Email" : "abc@abc.com"
        },
        "Settings" : {
          "Status" : "Pending"
        }
      }
    }
```

I added a rule too

```json
    "Invitation" : {
       ".indexOn": ["Info/Email","Settings/Status"]
    }
```

My AngularFire code is as follows:

```js
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Invitation');
    var userInvitations = rootRef.child("Info").orderByChild("Email").equalTo("abc@abc.com");
    var allInvitations = $firebaseArray(userInvitations);
```

But I am getting a **FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "Email" at /Invitation/Info to your security rules for better performance.** and of course I am not receiving any data.

What are the mistakes I made here? Also can I add multiple orderByChild, for example: if I want to find details of the record, which has "Info/Email" equal to "abc@abc.com" and "Settings/Status" equal to "Pending" ?

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase API only allows you to filter children one level deep
So with reference to your data structure:
if it were to be this way,

```json
    {  
      "-KhWrBcYyMluJbK7QpnK" : {
        "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
        "Settings" : {
          "Status" : "Accepted"
        }
      },
      "-KhX0tgQvDtDYqt4XRoL" : {
        "Email" : "abc@abc.com",
        "Settings" : {
          "Status" : "Accepted"
        }
      },
      "-KhX1eo7uFnOxqncDXQ5" : {
        "Email" : "abc@abc.com",
        "Settings" : {
          "Status" : "Pending"
        }
      }
    }
```

You should write your rules this way instead.

```json
    "Invitation" : {
       "Info" : {
          ".indexOn": "Email",
       },
       "Settings" : {
          ".indexOn": "Status",
       }
    }
```

Then you will be able to query the data

```js
    var allInvitations = [];
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Invitation');
    var userInvitations = rootRef.orderByChild("Email").equalTo("abc@abc.com");
    userInvitations.on('value', snap => {
        var invitations =  snap.val()
        for (prop in invitations ) {
         allInvitations.push(invitations[prop ]);
    
        }
        console.log(allInvitations);
    
    })
```